# SSH Logging all Comamnds

Tags: bash, ssh, administrator

I'm hiring a system administrator to do a short job for me but in order to be safe I'd like to log every command he does, how would I do so, or is it even possible? I know there is the (history) command but I'm pretty sure that only gives me the history for my SSH commands

Thanks.

**EDIT:** Someone marked this as a duplicate of another thread involving using the history command. However, the only flaw with that is the history command only logs commands ran in your SSH session/computer, if someone else runs commands I won't be able to see their history. So any ideas?

Comment: You can also remove entries from history and remove all entries.  Sounds like you should only give access to the commands this administrator will need to do the job.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [SSH Advanced Logging](http://superuser.com/questions/153357/ssh-advanced-logging)

Answer (score 2):

In order of increasing complexity, I would look at `rootsh` or `sudo`'s `LOG_OUTPUT` configuration options, or [`auditd`](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/206159/how-to-track-log-commands-executed-on-a-shell).  The last option is really the most complete, especially if you want to log *every* command this person does, even as non-root.